# I need to extract every nth char of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Ive been reading everything online but its not exactly what I need

```
var x = 'a1b2c3d4e5'
```

I need something to get me to

using 1 the answer should be `abcde`
using 2 the answer should be `12345`
using 3 the answer should be `b3e`

the idea behind it if using `1` it grabs `1` skips `1`
the idea behind it if using `2` it grabs `2` skips `2`
the idea behind it if using `3` it grabs `3` skips `3`

I dont want to use a for loop as it is way to long especially when your `x` is longer than 300000 chars.

is there a regex I can use or a function that Im not aware of?

*update*

I'm trying to some how implement your answers but when I use `1` that's when I face the problem. I did mention trying to stay away from for-loops the reason is resources on the server. The more clients connect the slower everything becomes. So far array.filter seem a lot quicker.

As soon as I've found it I'll accept the answer.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636010/extract-every-nth-letter-number

Comment: how would you get `b3e` ? like .. 3rd, 6th and 9th elements ?

Comment: https://github.com/hustcc/slice.js sounds like what youre looking for

Comment: Isn’t the for loop the same no matter how long the string is?

Comment: The regex engine is going to be using loops internally itself, likely in a much less efficient way than code specifically designed for your problem. It's not made of magic.

Comment: Existing answers have a difference in how they handle high Unicode (but none of them is necessarily correct in that respect). Do you need to handle non-ASCII text?

Comment: There seems to be something off with your expected results when given `1` as the nth character to be extracted. Every first character from `a1b2c3d4e5` would be `a1b2c3d4e5`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: so the Idea behind it is to grab 1 skip 1 then for 2 it would be grab 2 skip 2 etc etc

Answer (score 2):

As others point out, it's not like regular expressions are magic; there would still be an underlying looping mechanism. Don't worry though, when it comes to loops, 300,000 is nothing -

```js
console.time('while')

let x = 0

while (x++ < 300000)
  x += 1
  
console.timeEnd('while')
// while: 5.135 ms

console.log(x)
// 300000
```

Make a big string, who cares? 300,000 is nothing -

```js
// 10 chars repeated 30,000 times
const s =
  'abcdefghij'.repeat(30000) 

console.time('while string')

let x = 0
let interval = 2
let values = []
while (x < s.length)
{ values.push(s[x])
  x += interval
}

let result = values.join('')

console.timeEnd('while string')
// while string: 31.990ms

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// acegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegia...
// 150000
```

Or use an interval of 3 -

```js
const s =
  'abcdefghij'.repeat(30000) 

console.time('while string')

let x = 0
let interval = 3
let values = []
while (x < s.length)
{ values.push(s[x])
  x += interval
}

let result = values.join('')

console.timeEnd('while string')
// while string: 25.055ms

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// adgjcfibehadgjcfibehadgjcfibehadgjcfibe...
// 100000
```

Using a larger interval obviously results in fewer loops, so the total execution time is lower. The resulting string is shorter too.

```js
const s =
  'abcdefghij'.repeat(30000) 

console.time('while string')

let x = 0
let interval = 25 // big interval
let values = []
while (x < s.length)
{ values.push(s[x])
  x += interval
}

let result = values.join('')

console.timeEnd('while string')
// while string: 6.130

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// afafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafa...
// 12000
```

---

You can achieve functional style and stack-safe speed simultaneously -

```
const { loop, recur } = require('./lib')

const everyNth = (s, n) =>
  loop
    ( (acc = '', x = 0) =>
        x >= s.length
          ? acc
          : recur(acc + s[x], x + n)
    )

const s = 'abcdefghij'.repeat(30000)

console.time('loop/recur')
const result = everyNth(s, 2)
console.timeEnd('loop/recur')
// loop/recur: 31.615 ms

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// acegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegia ...
// 150000
```

The two are easily implemented -

```
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f(...acc.values)
  return acc
}

// ...

module.exports =
  { loop, recur, ... }
```

And unlike the `[...str].filter(...)` solutions which will always iterate through *every* element, our custom `loop` is much more flexible and receives speed benefit when a higher interval `n` is used -

```
console.time('loop/recur')
const result = everyNth(s, 25)
console.timeEnd('loop/recur')
// loop/recur: 5.770ms

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// afafafafafafafafafafafafafafa...
// 12000
```

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f(...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const everyNth = (s, n) =>
  loop
    ( (acc = '', x = 0) =>
        x >= s.length
          ? acc
          : recur(acc + s[x], x + n)
    )

const s = 'abcdefghij'.repeat(30000)

console.time('loop/recur')
const result = everyNth(s, 2)
console.timeEnd('loop/recur')
// loop/recur: 31.615 ms

console.log(result)
console.log(result.length)
// acegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegiacegia ...
// 150000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not an expert of regex, I'd use some fancy es6 functions to filter your chars.

```js
var x = 'a1b2c3d4e5'
var n = 2;

var result = [...x].filter((char, index) => index % n == 0);

console.log(result);
```

Note that because `0 % 2` will also return `0`, this will always return the first char. You can filter the first char by adding another simple check.

`var result = [...x].filter((char, index) => index > 0 && index % n == 0);`

Comment: this copies the entire string and calls a lambda for each element. Using the smallest interval 2, (an interval of 1 would just copy the entire string), we already know at least 50% of the elements will be skipped. For an interval of 3, at least 66% will be skipped. For a significantly large input string, like the one in question, do you see why this is terribly inefficient now?

Comment: @user633183 I'd prove my function in a jsfiddle, but it ran out of memory while running the function... :P thanks for the detailed clarification

Comment: @DavidThomas that's just plainly untrue. In my answer, you can see I use a simple index which accesses substrings directly. The size of the interval determines how many elements can be skipped at a time. NB you do *not* have to perform operation(s) on each character.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant:

```js
function getNth(str, nth) {
  return [...str].filter((_, i) => (i + 1) % nth === 0).join('');
}

console.log(getNth('a1b2c3d4e5', 2)); // 12345

console.log(getNth('a1b2c3d4e5', 3)); // b3e
```

Comment: same as Robb216's answer; please see my comment

Comment: Yes, you are right. This solution is appropriate only if code terseness is preferred to runtime efficiency,

Comment: I made an update to my answer that shows you how to achieve code brevity and speed without making sacrifices like these

Comment: I love your suggestion but when you use 1 it doesnt work. Thats kinda the problem I'm having.

Comment: Should not it return just the same string if you ask for each 1st character?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest, to avoid having to iterate over the entire array, is to step straight into the known `nth`'s.

Here's a couple of flavors:

```
function nthCharSubstr(str, nth) {
    let res = "";
    for (let i = nth - 1; i < str.length; i += nth) {
        res += string[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

More ES6-y:

```
const nthCharSubstr = (str, nth) =>
    [...Array(parseInt(str.length / nth)).keys()] // find out the resulting number of characters and create and array with the exact length
        .map(i => nth + i * nth - 1)              // each item in the array now represents the resulting character's index
        .reduce((res, i) => res + str[i], "");    // pull out each exact character and group them in a final string
```

This solution considers [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563868/i-need-to-extract-every-nth-char-of-a-string-in-javascript#comment95928856_54563868) as being valid.